# Sum of negative elements in each column of a NumPy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, sum

Do you know how to sum up all negative elements in each column of a NumPy array.
For example

```
>>> d
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [-1, -1,  9],
       [ 7, -6,  4]])
```

I need to get `[-1,-7,0]`. Is there a function to do so?

Answer (score 13):

Few approaches could be suggested, as listed below -

```
((d<0)*d).sum(0)
np.where(d<0,d,0).sum(0)
np.einsum('ij,ij->j',d<0,d)
((d - np.abs(d)).sum(0))/2
```

Sample step-by-step run with explanation for all those approaches -

1) Input array :

```
In [3]: d
Out[3]: 
array([[ 1,  2,  3],
       [-1, -1,  9],
       [ 7, -6,  4]])
```

2) Mask of negative elements :

```
In [4]: d<0
Out[4]: 
array([[False, False, False],
       [ True,  True, False],
       [False,  True, False]], dtype=bool)
```

3) Get masked negative elements off input array using element-wise multiplication :

```
In [5]: (d<0)*d
Out[5]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1, -1,  0],
       [ 0, -6,  0]])
```

4) Finally, sum along `axis=0` to sum along each column :

```
In [6]: ((d<0)*d).sum(axis=0) # Or simply ((d<0)*d).sum(0)
Out[6]: array([-1, -7,  0])
```

Approach#2 : 3) Get step (3) results alternatively with `np.where` :

```
In [7]: np.where(d<0,d,0)
Out[7]: 
array([[ 0,  0,  0],
       [-1, -1,  0],
       [ 0, -6,  0]])
```

Approach#3 : 3,4) Perform elementwise multiplication between mask and array and get the summation, all in one step using `np.einsum` -

```
In [8]: np.einsum('ij,ij->j',d<0,d)
Out[8]: array([-1, -7,  0])
```

Approach#4 : Get the absolute values of input array and subtract from the array itself, giving us double of the negative elements and the positive values being canceled out :

```
In [9]: d - np.abs(d)
Out[9]: 
array([[  0,   0,   0],
       [ -2,  -2,   0],
       [  0, -12,   0]])
```

Sum along each column and divide by 2 for desired output :

```
In [10]: (d - np.abs(d)).sum(0)
Out[10]: array([ -2, -14,   0])

In [11]: ((d - np.abs(d)).sum(0))/2
Out[11]: array([-1, -7,  0])
```

Comment: The last approach has two downsides: It can lead to overflow where the others would still work and it would give a float array in python3. Maybe better `((d - np.abs(d)) // 2).sum(0)` (that doesn't take care of all overflow issues but at least of some).

Comment: thanks a lot! i just want to make sure i understood - for the first option -((d<0)*d).sum(0)- the zero inside the sum is for the axis (cols) and the *d (the second d) is because that inside the Brackets we got true/false matrix (e.g. zeros and ones) - so after that, in order to get the sum - we have to multiply by d?

Comment: @noamishal Check out the just added step by step run with explanation if that helps out.

Comment: @noamishal Did the posted solution and the comments clarify your doubts?